# Java execute .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, command

I am using windows 7 and program in Netbeans platform. I have wrote this line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start make.bat");
```

When I run the bat it works perfectly, but then java calls it this is what I get:

> ```
> C:\Users\RB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BinaryTree>dot -T png -o tree.png tree.dot
>
> 'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\RB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BinaryTree>cmd
> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
> Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> ```

The contents of the bath file is:

```
dot -T png -o tree.png tree.dot
```

Comment: Can you provide the details what is written in that .bat file ?

Comment: i had provided them. as i wrote:
the contents of the bath file are: dot -T png -o tree.png tree.dot

Comment: dot is a program that paints binary tree out of text file

Comment: what location is the 'dot' program in? do batch files execute programs relative to their location or relative to the location of the command line invoking them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify full path to 'dot' program in your bat file. It is possible thet environment variables like PATH are not the same in Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and your OS.

Comment: This is most likeley to be the case, but now i'm having trouble with providing path with blank spaces. like D:\Program Files\... anyway i'm working on it

Comment: I've solved it by rewriting bath file to 
"D:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.28\bin\dot" -T png -o tree.png tree.dot